# Open gnome-terminal without sourcing .bashrc

Tags: linux, bash, terminal, gnome-terminal

Since my `.bashrc` contains a lot of aliases, variables and lot of other stuff that changes the behavior of bash, from time to time I want to run `gnome-terminal` without sourcing it. I wonder if there's some easy way how to do this without the need to temporarily rename `.bashrc` or delete its contents.

Comment: You could configure `gnome-terminal` to use another shell than `bash` (assuming, of course, you do not need bash-specific features in the first place).

Answer (score 9):

You can run `bash` without sourcing `.bashrc`:

```
bash --norc
```

Then it is just a matter of creating a `gnome-terminal` profile which runs that `bash` command, rather than the default.

Answer (score 3):

Another option, besides the one already mentioned (`bash --norc`) is a simple evaluation in the beginning of your `~/.bashrc` and skip the rest in case you're running inside a gnome terminal.

For example, you might rely on the fact that other terminal emulators and remote SSH logins as well as local logins from virtual consoles don't set variable `COLORTERM`. Armed with this little bit of information you could just wrap everything in your `~/.bashrc` inside a conditional statement:

```
if [ "$COLORTERM" != 'gnome-terminal' ]; then
  # all your current stuff in ~/.bashrc
fi
```

That way you don't have to rely to gnome terminal settings, in case you don't want to.